# making a rectangular star shape with 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to make a rectangular star shape with 8086 assembly using 1 loop and making the outer one with cmp to 0 and jne the code is below.

Here's my code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
ml db 'how many lines you want',13,10,'$'
ms db 'how many stars in each line',13,10,'$'
lines db 0
stars db 0

nl db 13,10,'$'
.code
Main Proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov dx, OFFSet ml
mov ah,9h
int 21h

mov ah,1h
int 21h

sub al,'0'

mov [line],al
int 21h

xor ah,ah

mov dx, OFFSet ms
mov ah,9h
int 21h

mov ah,1h
int 21h

sub al,'0'

mov [stars],al
int 21h

mov cx,[stars]
int 21h


outer:
dec [line]
mov cl,[stars]
int 21h
inner:
mov dl, '*'
mov ah, 2h
int 21h
loop inner

mov dx, OFFSet nl
mov ah,9h
int 21h

cmp [line],0
jne outer

 MOV AH,4CH
 INT 21H

Main ENDP
END Main
```

Comment: Please format your code properly as this is hard to read.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I'm guessing OP just means a rectangle made out of asterisk characters, but yeah, the wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm guessing since you posted this question that your code isn't working the way you expected it to. But you haven't told us what your expected output is, or what your actual output is. There's really nothing to be answered here right now, since you haven't actually asked any question or described any problem.

Answer (score 1):

> a recktagular star shape

It is true that this wording is confusing, but the code clearly wants to draw a rectangle made out of asterisks.

The good news is that your nested loops are rather fine. However you have written lots of redundant `int 21h` instructions that serve no real purpose and are harmful! To be removed.

A big problem is that you are loading the `CH` register with a non-zero value and as a consequence, the first run of the inner loop will draw too many stars.

> ```
> stars db 0
> nl db 13,10,'$'
> ```

The `mov cx,[stars]` instruction not only loads *stars* in `CL` but also it loads the number 13 in `CH`.

This is a cleaned version of your code:

```
mov dx, OFFSet ml
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, '0'
mov [line], al

mov dx, OFFSet ms
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, '0'
mov [stars], al

outer:
  mov  cl, [stars]
  mov  ch, 0                  <<<<< Because LOOP uses CX
inner:
  mov  dl, '*'
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  loop inner
  mov  dx, OFFSet nl
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h

  dec  [line]
  jnz  outer
```

Instead of `dec [line]` and `cmp [line], 0`, you can conditionally jump (`jnz outer`) based on the Zero Flag that is already defined by the `dec` instruction.

---

It's just as easy to not use `LOOP` at all (because later you'll have to un-learn it, really)

```
outer:
  mov  cl, [stars]
inner:
  mov  dl, '*'
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h
  dec  cl                  <<<<<<
  jnz  inner               <<<<<<
  mov  dx, OFFSet nl
  mov  ah, 09h
  int  21h

  dec  [line]
  jnz  outer
```